# Storing nested child nodes from a WebService XML response as array of arrays in ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, web-services

I am trying to compare response XML of a Web Service with values from database.

I have a SOAP WebService response XML stored in a variable as a `RestClient::Response` as given below:

Each node & node values inside every item tag needs to be compared against the result of a db query, i.e after running a db query
    first row of the query result is `['Reason 1', 'T', 'OPEN', '2019-05-20', '2019-06-04', 'T']`. Similarly other rows also denote
    values which needs to be compared against every other child node values inside item tag. Using ruby I have stored the db query result as an array of arrays, where every inner array is a row.

How do I store all child node values inside every item tag as an array of arrays so that I can compare them with db values? For example:

`[["Reason 1", "T", "OPEN", "2019-05-20", "2019-06-04", "T"], ["Reason 3", "T", "OPEN", "2019-05-20", "2019-05-28", "T"]]`

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <a:Details xmlns:a="http://service.test.ws.project/">
         <items>
            <item>
               <reason>Reason 2</reason>
               <DisplayInWeb>F</DisplayInWeb>
               <status>OPEN</status>
               <availableDate>2019-05-20</availableDate>
               <expiryDate>2019-05-21</expiryDate>
               <sold>T</sold>
            </item>
            <item>
               <reason>Reason 1</reason>
               <DisplayInWeb>T</DisplayInWeb>
               <status>OPEN</status>
               <availableDate>2019-05-20</availableDate>
               <expiryDate>2019-06-04</expiryDate>
               <sold>T</sold>
            </item>
            <item>
               <reason>Reason 3</reason>
               <DisplayInWeb>T</DisplayInWeb>
               <status>OPEN</status>
               <availableDate>2019-05-20</availableDate>
               <expiryDate>2019-05-28</expiryDate>
               <sold>F</sold>
            </item>
           <Count>3</Count>
         </items>
      </a:Details>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

```rb
def get_response_node_values_as_array(parent_tag_name)
    response_xml = Nokogiri::XML $response
    puts response_xml
    child_arr = Array.new
    response_xml.xpath("//#{parent_tag_name}").each { |node|
      searched_field_arr << node.value
         }
    return child_arr
end
```

I was passing parent tag name which here is item as an argument to the method.
Expecting it to return an array of arrays with values of child nodes available under every parent.